# Android thread Nullpointer exception

Tags: android

I have just started Android Development, I want to make thread in my application which reads XML document and returns a view which is to be displayed by **createTabContent** of **tabHost**.

I tried it but getting exception

> ```
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422): java.lang.NullPointerException
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at android.widget.TabHost$FactoryContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:622)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
> 12-08 10:33:52.684: E/AndroidRuntime(422):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

```
package com.mahesh;

import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CricTask extends TabActivity implements TabHost.TabContentFactory{
    TabHost tabHost;
    Context context;
     ScrollView scroll;
     LinearLayout layout;
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         tabHost = getTabHost();
        // MaheshActivity main=new MaheshActivity();
         //scroll = new ScrollView(this);
      context=getApplicationContext();
       //layout=new LinearLayout(context);
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Current")
                .setIndicator("Current")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, List1.class)));


        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Result")
                .setIndicator("Result").setContent(this));
                //.setContent(new Intent(this, MaheshActivity.class).putExtra("link", "http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml")));

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("News")
                .setIndicator("News")
                .setContent(new Intent(this,MaheshActivity.class)
                        .putExtra("link", "http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/content/story/feeds/0.xml")));




    }



@Override
public View createTabContent(String tag) {


    if(ta..equals("Current")){
      new Thread(new Runnable() { 
          public void run(){

              XmlHandler handle = null;

                TextView name[];
                TextView website[];

                URL web;

                //setContentView(R.layout.layout);

                 scroll = new ScrollView(context);
                 layout=new LinearLayout(context);
                layout.setOrientation(1);
                //ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);

                try {

                    web = new URL("http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml");

                        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                        SAXParser sax = factory.newSAXParser();
                        XMLReader xmlread = sax.getXMLReader();
                        handle = new XmlHandler();
                        xmlread.setContentHandler(handle);
                        xmlread.parse(new InputSource(web.openStream()));

                    }           
                    catch(NullPointerException n){
                                n.getMessage();
                                }

                catch (Exception e) {

                  e.getMessage();

                }
                SitesList sitesList = handle.sitesList;

                name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
                website = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];

                for (int i = 1; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {

                    name[i] = new TextView(context);
                    name[i].setText(sitesList.getName().get(i));
                    name[i].setTextSize(20);
                    name[i].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    website[i] = new TextView(context);

                    String str = "\"" + sitesList.getWebsite().get(i) + "\"";
                    //String link = sitesList.getWebsite().get(i);
                    String html = "<a" + " " + "href" + "=" + "\\" + str + ">"
                            + str + "</a>";

                    website[i].setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
                    website[i].setAutoLinkMask(BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                    website[i].setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    website[i].setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

                    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
                    layout.addView(tv);
                    layout.addView(name[i]);
                    layout.addView(website[i]);

                }
                scroll.addView(layout);
               }


          }).start();

        return scroll;
    }


}

}
```

Comment: URL("http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml");
 SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
 SAXParser sax = factory.newSAXParser();
 XMLReader xmlread = sax.getXMLReader();
handle = new XmlHandler();xmlread.setContentHandler(handle);
 xmlread.parse(new InputSource(web.openStream()));}                    catch(NullPointerException { n.getMessage();     }          
catch (Exception e) {
               e.getMessage();}

Comment: try { web = new 
   SitesList sitesList = handle.sitesList;
 name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
 website = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
for (int i = 1; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {   
 name[i] = new TextView(context);         name[i].setText(sitesList.getName().get(i));
 name[i].setTextSize(20);
 name[i].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
  website[i] = new TextView(context);
 String str = "\"" + sitesList.getWebsite().get(i) + "\"";     String html = "<a" + " " + "href" + "=" + "\\" + str + ">"+ str + "</a>";

Comment: here is the code help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you haven't posted your code yet, but I am still going to take a stab at this, since you said you are new at developing apps. Are you using the `Thread`class? In `Android`, you need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead if you want to update the UI from your Thread process.  Be sure to read up on developer.android.com, too. Hope this helps.

Comment: i got it by using async-task but i have to place a progress dialog when a tab is clicked because its takes time for reading xml from net.using asynctask when tab is clicked screen hanges and when view is ready to be displayed then progress dialog starts and dismisses.so i am trying using thread >> Thanks for the reply

Comment: @mahesh I won't be able to help any more without seeing your code. Good luck with your problem.